# php preg_replace function wrong result

Tags: php, regex, function, preg-replace

I am trying to remove (most) special chars from a user given $_POST string, before inserting it into the database, with the following preg_replace function:

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-._äöü]/', '', $description);
```

Now, when entering this for $description:

```
abc !"§$%&/()=?`*'#+´ß
```

The result is just:

```
?
```

Why is the function removing abc, but is keeping the '?', which is not in my whitelist of preg_replace?
Any answers are much apreciated.

Comment: `echo preg_replace('/\W/', '', $string);`

Comment: You are using a negated character class (see `[^`)

Comment: When not using the `^` i get `()=?`*'#+´?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP should be configured for UTF-8. Set the [`default_charset`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset) INI option to `'UTF-8'`; use the `u` [pattern modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
$description = 'abc !"§$%&/()=?`*\'#+´ß.';
$r = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-\._äöü]/u', '', $description);
var_dump($r);
```

*Sample output*

```
string(4) "abc."
```

Also, consider setting a UTF-8 locale, since functions such as `basename` are locale-aware:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,
  'de_DE.UTF-8',
  'de_DE.utf8',
  'en_US.UTF-8',
  'en_US.utf8'
);
```

Comment: returns an empty string here. php.ini default_charset was already set to UTF-8

Comment: @toni_latenz, are you sure that `$description` is non-empty? Could you try exactly the code in the answer for test?

Comment: Got it, had used the `basename()` function on the variable before using the `preg_replace()` function.

Comment: @toni_latenz, well, then you should `setlocale()` as well. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `'/\W/'` will remove all special characters:

```
<?php
$string = 'abc !"§$%&/()=?*#+´ß';
echo preg_replace('/\W/', '', $string); // abc
?>
```

Comment: when using echo preg_replace('/\W/', '', $string);

Comment: i get ?ß from the string abc !"§$%&/()=?*#+´ß

Comment: @toni_latenz: print where u need to echo

Comment: @toni_latenz: i have checked `$string = 'abc !"§$%&/()=?*#+´ß';` it gives me `abc`

Comment: gives me abc��ß

Comment: @toni_latenz: try this `echo preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\']/', '', $string);`

Answer (score 0):

```
function clean($string) {
   $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.

   return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.
}
```

**How to use :**

```
echo clean('a|"bc!@£de^&$f g');
```